# Library for pattern matching shapeless coproduct with partial functions

Tags: scala, generic-programming, shapeless, coproduct

I have a *relatively* ergonomic pattern I use to pattern match shapeless `Coproduct`s. It looks basically like this

```scala
val stringOrInt: String :+: Int :+: CNil  = Coproduct("Hello world")

implicit class Coproduct2Syntax[A, B](val value: A :+: B :+: CNil) extends AnyVal {
  type cop = A :+: B :+: CNil

  def comatch[Z](
    caseA: PartialFunction[A, Z],
    caseB: PartialFunction[B, Z]
  ): Z = {
    val a = Function.unlift[cop, Z](_.select[A].flatMap(caseA.lift))
    val b = Function.unlift[cop, Z](_.select[B].flatMap(caseB.lift))
    a.orElse(b).apply(value)
  }
}

stringOrInt.comatch({
  case s => s.length
},{
  case i => i
})
// Int = 11
```

This works well enough but I haven't gone through the trouble of defining `CoproductNSyntax` for 0-22.

I'm aware we can do something similar with `Poly1`, but that requires defining a separate object

My question is: are there any existing libraries that provide this type of pattern for matching for `Coproduct`s?

Comment: Shapeless works mostly with `Poly`s. You can generate code for `CoproductNSyntax` like it's done [in Scala library](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/project/genprod.scala) or [in Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/project/Boilerplate.scala) or maybe with [Scalameta](https://scalameta.org/).

Comment: It's a little unclear what the intended behavior is. If a partial function of the appropriate type doesn't match, should you continue on to try to find another possible matching element? What if none match? Why not use `Function1`? Is this just for the partial function syntax?

Comment: For what it's worth if for some reason I _really_ didn't want to use a polymorphic function value here (which I think is the "right" answer), I'd just pattern match on the `Inr`s and `Inl`s. This is mostly a matter of taste, though, and you can probably make your approach work comfortably—as far as I know this kind of thing doesn't already exist, though.

Comment: @TravisBrown the intended behavior here would be that if there is no match then it would continue looking for a match in the next PF. Thinking about it, that intention only makes sense in one obscure case. In another incarnation of this I have a method that returned `PartialFunction[A :+: B :+: CNil, Z]` so having no match made more sense there. Is there any way to use a polymorphic function value inline (I don't have it in front of me to try, but I recall it not working in the obvious way)?